# Passing an array in Controller Route in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

**OBJECTIVE:** I want to download multiple PDF files in a single Zip file.

I have an array of the filename in variable `filenameList`. I am trying to pass this array variable to the `statementController.php` through a request from `dashboard.blade.php` view using Controller Route method (Passing array in URL)

**VIEW:**

```
<tr class="product-box">
   <td>{{@$key+1}}</td>
   <td style="text-transform: uppercase;">@if(@$value->analyse_bankname!=null) {{@$value->analyse_bankname}} @else {{@$value->bankname}} @endif  <a href="/analytics/download-report-zip/{{@$value->filenameList}}/{{@$value->job_id}}"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function downloadZip(Request $request)
    {
        try 
        {
            $filenames = $request->$filenameList;
            $job_id = $job_id;
            $zip = new \ZipArchive;
            $zip->open($zipname, \ZipArchive::CREATE);
            foreach ($filenames as $filename){
                $zip->addFile($file);
            }
            $zip->close;
            @$path = '../storage/app/public/bks/case_1/'.$zipname;

            return response()->download($path);
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

**ROUTE:**

```
  Route::get('/download-report-zip/{filename}/{job_id}','analyticsAuth\statementController@downloadZip')->name('bank statement download');
```

**Empty filename variable in URL**

```
domain.com/analytics/download-report-zip?filename=&job_id=aRj0zc6WxA3Kq9FEdtwH
```

Answer (score 0):

trying changing your a tag like this
`<a href="/analytics/download-report-zip/'.{{$value->filenameList}}.'/'.{{$value->job_id}}.'"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>`

Comment: This is giving me **Error_Exception: Undefined property: stdClass::$filenameList**

Comment: u are having a problem in your controller

Comment: I think so I have an issue in VIEW rather than Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest to just serialize the array before you send it through the GET request:

```
<?php $list = urlencode(serialize($value->filenameList)) ?>
<a href="/analytics/download-report-zip/{{$list}}/{{@$value->job_id}}">
```

Then decode in the Controller:

```
public function downloadZip(Request $request, $filenames, $id){
    $filenames = unserialize(urldecode($filenames));
```

**Please note the variables injected into the** `downloadZip` method - this is coming in from your routing like this.

It's not the cleanest, but it is probably the easiest if your array isn't too large.  Be careful though. The maximum size of a GET request is limited to 4k, which can blow up pretty quickly when serializing.

Comment: This is still showing me **Undefined property: stdClass::$filenameList**

Comment: On the controller or the view?  If on the controller, you should have no reference to a variable named `filenameList` unless it is still in there (if so, take it out and keep it like I wrote in the controller).  If it is showing on the VIEW, then you have a totally unrelated problem to your original question :)

Comment: This throwing me Error on VIEW.

Comment: OK, well good news is this answer should solve your question above... bad news is that the error you see (undefined prop) is unrelated.  That error is coming from the original controller that is sending the `$value` object to the original view.  Your original controller is not assigning `filenameList` to `$value`.  Maybe not the controller - maybe you assign it in the view?  Either way, that assignment of `filenameList` is not happening.

Comment: I read somewhere that we can use AJAX to pass a multidimensional array. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Sure.  You can stringify / serialize and send with AJAX in the data segment as POST or GET.  But your error is not from sending -- that is solved I think.  The error is because something is not getting assigned to the `filenameList` property.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for the late reply. I do have noticed that I'm not getting anything in the `filename` parameter while hovering over link.